# What to use for building a service tier in PHP?

Tags: php, wcf, web-services, service

I come from a MS / C# / .Net background, and am accustomed to everything that the .Net Framework has to offer, including WCF.  When building a service tier in .Net, the choice of what framework to use is easy: WCF.  WCF gives you the ability to write something once, and the flexibility to expose that functionality in multiple ways and in a variety of serialization tactics using only a configuration change.

As a newcomer to PHP, I'm trying to determine what libraries / APIs / frameworks in PHP can rival what WCF has to offer.  What is the best library / API / framework / approach to use when beginning to construct a service tier in PHP?  Is there anything that can do what WCF does in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather broad and I am not sure if there is a direct translation from Windows to PHP. However, you can try looking at some web services frameworks like this one:
http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php/

In addition there are some MVC frameworks who may provide some of the similar approaches such as http://cakephp.org/.